# Can I make Next 14, next-intl, output: 'export', and event handlers work together?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js14

I am migrating part of a large legacy PHP/Jquery application to NextJS (and learing Next/React in the process).
I cannot use React on the server so I need `output: 'export'`.
The application is very interactive and has a lot of buttons with `onClick` and a text that needs to appear in a chosen language. Something like `<button onClick={doTheThing}>{t('click_for_the_thing')}</button>`.

I followed a few tutorials and documentation, f.ex. https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/environments/server-client-components but it seems they all assume a non-static server.

I was expecting that handling interactive and multilingual content would be easy in a modern framework but it seems this is not the case, even without the `output: 'export'` requiremet.
So maybe I am barking at the wrong tree ?

Are there better suited alternatives to next-intl ? I really do not care about dynamic routing, I just need that the user is able to somehow pick a language and see text in that language (this is also all behind login, so SEO and the like are not a concern).